# Riemann Invariants

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gas

I understand that the Riemann Invariants for an expansion wave (isentropic) are constant along the particular characteristic line i.e.:

$u + \frac{2c}{\gamma-1} = const $ along $dx/dt=u+a$ (1)

Entropy $s = const$ along $dx/dt=u$ (2)

$u - \frac{2c}{\gamma-1} = const $ along $dx/dt=u-a$ (3)

This is determined by multiplying the inverse right Eigenvector matrix with the primitive state vector $[ d\rho, du, dP ]^T$ and then integrating the resulting equation

Another method some authors use is to divide the primitive state vector by the respective Eigenvector components for each wave. E.g. for the left running wave:

$\frac{d\rho}{K_1} = \frac{du}{K_2} = \frac{dP}{K_3}$ (4)

Where $K_i$ are the components of the Eigenvector that corresponds to the respective Eigenvalue (wave speed $\lambda = dx/dt$). Thus, for the left running wave (dx/dt = u-a), we get the Riemann invariants (1) and (2) from (4).

Thus, these two invariants correspond to the characteristic (3), i.e. they are constant along this characteristic.

I am now confused by the statements (1) (2) and (3), which state that each invariant is constant along that respective characteristic line Vs. the invariants (1) and (2) correspond to the wave characteristic (3).

Does this then imply that all invariants are constant along all three of those characteristic lines? How does one obtain the equation (4), I could not find this anywhere?